# In ubuntu IDE doest load tkinter library for python3 or python2

Tags: software-installation, python, python3, ide

Hello everyone and thank you for your help in advance.

I am trying to use tkinter library.
When I open terminal type python3 and use

```
import tkinter
tkinter._test()
```

It works.
Also when I type python and use

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.TK()
```

It also works.
My problem is when I install on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS
IDE like for eg. Eric Python or VISUAL STUDIO etc.
Under python2 or python3 I get same error and can not load tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

When I load my simple code I get this error:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError

No module named 'Tkinter'
  File "/home/user234/Desktop/Program/start.py", line 1, in 
    import Tkinter
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
This is the code I use

```
import Tkinter
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas()
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(10, 100, 200, 100, 10, 200)
```

Any suggestions where could be problem? I could not google answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
When using IDE you need to add this to your code to use tkinter library:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```